# How do I determine if Magento is running on Apache programmatically?

Tags: php, apache, magento, nginx

I am looking for an elegant solution to figure out if Magento is running on Apache or Nginx programmatically. Once I know the web server I will also need to know if `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: check out $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']  - http://serverfault.com/questions/164130/how-to-detect-in-php-if-it-is-running-on-apache-nginx-or-some-other-webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link from user "utility" I was able to find the closest solution. I'll have to check the Server Software key. Ultimately I will have to ask the user to confirm...

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"].
```

Thanks!

Chuck

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

This will give you more information than you need ..

I thought this would tell you if mod_rewrite was enabled, but it won't.

You can always check that in an `.htaccess` file.  If you set `RewriteEngine On` it should do what you ask it .. ie:

```
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ yourfile.php?link=$1 [L]
```

If a rewrite rule you KNOW works fails ...  mod_rewrite is most likely disabled.